# How to load more at the top of the screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to load more items at the top of the screen into a ListView widget and continue scrolling from the position I was before loading more items?

I know how to detect the bottom of the ListView or the top of the list. Like this:

```dart
_scrollListener() {
    if (_controller.offset >= _controller.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_controller.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        // reach the bottom - load more items
      });
    }
    if (_controller.offset <= _controller.position.minScrollExtent &&
        !_controller.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        //reach the top - load more items
      });
    }
  }
```

So, when I'm loading data at the bottom of the list, new items just appending to the existing list and it looks natural because the user can continue scrolling down without any problems.

**The problem is**: When I updated the list of items, scroll started from the top of the screen (0 pixels position), not from the item' position I was right before loading more items.

**What I've tried**: I've tried calculating the height of the loaded items and then jump to the calculated extent in pixels, but it didn't work well, because the size of elements in my ListView can be dynamic and this calculates the wrong number of pixels I have to scroll.

**The question is the following**: How to achieve the same ListView behavior while loading items into the start of the list?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @LukeIrvin the accepted answer really helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maybe use something like the method described here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12319#issuecomment-488170337

Write something like this:

```
      CustomScrollView(center: aKey, slivers: [
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [...new items...].reversed.toList(),  
          ),
        ),
        SliverList(
          key: aKey,
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [...old items...],
          ),
        ),
      ]);
```

You can play with the types of Delegates as make sense.  Then a scroll offset of 0 should put the old first item at the top.

Comment: When you need to reload at the bottom, the use of CustomScrollView's `anchor` property may help.